# Should I use pandas dictionary? How?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a data frame like this:

| Code |
| --- |
| DA |
| DB |
| DC |
| DD |
| DE |
| DF |
| DG |
| DX |
| DY |
| DZ |

And I want to add a column to the table above so that each value in the code column has a fixed value like the table below:

| Code | Value |
| --- | --- |
| DA | A |
| DB | A |
| DC | A |
| DD | B |
| DE | B |
| DF | B |
| DG | C |
| DX | C |
| DY | C |

How should I do this ??

Comment: What is the connection between the title to the question? what is *pandas dictionary* anyway?

Comment: The naive solution will be `df['value'] = ['A', 'A',...]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'Code': ['DA', 'DB', 'DC', 'DD', 'DE', 'DF', 'DG', 'DX', 'DY']} )
dct = {'DA': 'A', 'DB': 'A', 'DC': 'A',
       'DD': 'B', 'DE': 'B', 'DF': 'B',
       'DG': 'C', 'DX': 'C', 'DY': 'C'}
df['Value'] = df['Code'].replace(dct)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Code Value
0   DA     A
1   DB     A
2   DC     A
3   DD     B
4   DE     B
5   DF     B
6   DG     C
7   DX     C
8   DY     C
```

**An example with a certain pattern:**

```
df['Value'] = df['Code'].apply(lambda s: chr((int(ord(s[-1])) - 65) // 3 + 65))
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
0   DA     A # matches the desired result
1   DB     A # matches the desired result
2   DC     A # matches the desired result
3   DD     B # matches the desired result
4   DE     B # matches the desired result
5   DF     B # matches the desired result
6   DG     C # matches the desired result
7   DX     H # no match
8   DY     I # no match
```

Comment: I have a file that contains thousands of code columns in the table above, is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: If the number of combinations of `Code` is large, it is advisable to find a pattern, if it exists, between `Code` and `Value` and form the result based on the formula.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Value = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C']
df['Value'] = Value
```